# system crash after declaring global object of the class

Tags: c++, pointers, global, unsafe-pointers

I am very new to c++. I am getting system crash (not compilation error) in doing following:

I am declaring global pointer of class.

```
BGiftConfigFile  *bgiftConfig;
class BGiftConfigFile : public EftBarclaysGiftConfig { }
```

in this class I am reading tags from XML file. it is crashing system when this pointer is used to retrieve value. I am doing coding for verifone terminal.

```
int referenceSetting = bgiftConfig->getreferencesetting(); //system error
```

getreferencesetting() is member function of class **EftBarclaysGiftConfig**

I am confused about behavior of pointer in this case. I know I am doing something wrong but couldn't rectify it.

When I declare one object of class locally it retrieves the value properly.

```
BGiftConfigFile  bgiftConfig1; 
int referenceSetting = bgiftConfig1.getreferencesetting(); //working
```

But if I declare this object global it also crashes the system.

I need to fetch values at different location in my code so I forced to use something global.

How to rectify this problem?

Comment: What creates the object that the pointer is pointing to?

Comment: i am referencing local instance using '.'

Comment: Your local is a stack allocated instance.  Your global is a pointer.  Are you allocating it (like bgiftConfigFile = new BGiftConfigFile();)?

Comment: i am not allocating it but if i use new then it is also throwing system error.
    BGiftConfigFile  *bgiftConfig= new(BGiftConfigFile);//system error

Comment: it is related to null pointer

Comment: Looks like you might be declaring and allocating a new local rather than just allocating the global.

Comment: If the global has no reason to be a pointer, then just making the instance global should do. You wouldn't want to make arbitrary globals pointers, and then initialize them on the heap for no reason.

Answer (score 1):

Your local is a stack allocated instance.

Your global is a pointer and needs to be allocated via a call to new before you start using it:

```
bgiftConfig = new BGiftConfigFile();
```

Comment: Globals have static storage duration and are zero-initialized already.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly forward declare the class BGiftConfigFile and then declare your pointer to object of the class as follows

```
class BGiftConfigFile
 BGiftConfigFile  *bgiftConfig;
class BGiftConfigFile : public EftBarclaysGiftConfig { };
```

Then allocate space for your pointer object using new operator

```
bgiftConfig = new BGiftConfigFile(); // depends upon what constructors you have defined in your class
```

After you are done with your pointer delete it appropriated using delete operator

```
delete bgiftConfig;
```

Comment: More complication than needed in both declaring the global and managing it.

Comment: actully it is not possible to pass object to functions .we are not calling fuctions just returning next event which indirectly calls the fuction

Answer (score 1):

> i need to fetch values at different location in my code so i forced to use someting global.

No, you don't need something global.  You can pass your non-global instance of this object to the code that needs it.